# vector summation with constrains

Tags: linear-algebra

In $R^N$ space, there are $m$ vectors $v_1, v_2, \cdots, v_m, v_i\in R^N$. 
The direction of $v_i$ can be inverted, i.e. $v_i=-v_i$.

The objective is to get a new vector $v=\sum_{i=1}^{m}v_i$ whose every component is as small as possible .

I.e. try to find $a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_m, a_i\in \left\{ 1,-1\right\}$,
$$v=\sum_{i=1}^m a_iv_i$$ 
minimise any norm of $v$, i.e., minimise every component of vector $v$

I do not want to treat this as a constrained optimization problem.

I thought may be one could try to find two similar vectors in the same or inverted direction and then delete both. As I was suggested, $v_2+v_8+v_{23}=-v_3$ would happen. So this is not a possible way.

Comment: In what sense do you want to minimize the object that is **vector** ? What;s your target function?

Comment: I correct it. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but your question is very unclear. Suggest you write it more detailed and edit the language so one can get what you are asking for. Yet understand you have a tuple and want to have the elements reduced to max. But not sure if that is possible without a constraint.

Comment: How could you know to limit yourself to looking for two similar vectors? What if $v_1 + v_2 + \cdots + v_n \approx v_k$?

Comment: And what's more peculiar that we just have a discrete space of possible variants.

Comment: What about finding the nullspace of $\mathbf{V}=\left[ v_1, \dots, v_m\right]$ and then searching for the vector of $\pm1$'s that is closest to it?

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, Yes, thank you. I thought this you mentioned.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, yes, thank you. But how could I draw it to ±1's? If possible, I do not want to make it complex, e.g. adding constrains.

Comment: @Vivian I am not sure that it even makes sense. If the nullspace is just the zero vector, then every combination of $\pm 1$ is the same distance from it. However, if $\mathbf{p}$ is the vector of $\pm 1$'s, then, since $\Vert \mathbf{p} \Vert = \sqrt{M}$, you can at least bound things by $\lambda_{min} M \leq \Vert \mathbf{Vp} \Vert^2 \leq \lambda_{max} M$, where $\lambda_{min}$ and $\lambda_{max}$ are the smallest and largest eigenvalues of $\mathbf{V}^\mathrm{T} \mathbf{V}$, respectively.

Comment: @AnonSubmitter85, what you give is the bounds.